# Impact of $('script').detach();

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After having loaded all the scripts in a page, can I safely call `$('script').detach();` to remove the scripts from the DOM?

Note: It is the equivalent of `Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("script")).forEach(script => script.remove())`

Doing so would reduce the number of Node in the page and make certain queries faster (ex: `$('*')` ).

Are there any side effects of doing so? If not, why doesn't everyone use this trick?

Answer (score 1):

you can, but in fact - if you use `*` selector a lot - tag script not your major problem.

And if you have more than 3-7-10 scripts on your pages - that's the sign to check your page/coding pipeline

So the answer is - yes, you can

Extended answer - in normal situation it won't give you any pos